# after kafkaTemplate.send(topic, avdlObject); appends dataType in value

Tags: java, spring-kafka, kafka-topic

I have kafka template and avdl schema.
avdl schema format:

```
recors name{
  union {null, int } a;
  union {null, string} b;
}
```

now i call kafkaTemplate.send(topic, nameObj);
when i try to consume this usig consfluent 5.4 then it return data in format:
{a: {"int": "123"}}

why int is appended in the response ?

Comment: Its the way avro serialization to json works. If you remove union, it will be just normal json, but you have null or int value so, deserializator need to know - what type it should parse

Comment: is there any way to have json without data type and also can handle null and int ?

Comment: I think it's imposible to do with standart avro serializator / deserializator. But may be someone can propose a solution for this problem.